# edit regedit value using bat file

Tags: cmd, regedit

I am trying to change the value of a `reg_dword` entry: `start` in location: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hidserv`
to value `2`.

I tried already exacting code from several sites, nothing works and I am launching it as admin:

```
REG.exe ADD "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hidserv" /t REG_DWORD /v Start /d 2 /f
REG ADD "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hidserv" /t REG_DWORD /v Start /d 2 /f
REG.exe ADD "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hidserv" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

On every site there was information with slight difference, but i don't think order matter, maybe `""`.

What is the correct syntax for adding a registry value as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `Computer`.
Indeed, the order of the options does not matter. Also it doesn't matter if you call `REG` or `REG.exe`.

Usually, the inbuilt help is also your friend:

`reg add /?`

Which tells you that `Computer` is the (network) name of the remote computer and can be omitted to use the current (local) computer as default.

This line works fine (as any other of yours without the `Computer\`:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hidserv" /t REG_DWORD /v Start /d 3 /f
```

Offtopic: Check out the other networks of stackexchange. I'd think this question would be more suitable for https://superuser.com/.